# Porque meu Ajax retorna um codigo HTML ao invés de só retornar o valor? Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Bom dia Galera, tudo beleza?

Estou a dias tentando retornar um valor da minha view para meu controller usando codeigniter. Porém não quero que aconteça refresh na página.

Então decidir usar o ajax, porém na minha consulta ou ele vem com o codigo html da minha pagina ou ele da esse erro:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

Meu HTML:

```html
<form real="form" id="form" nome="form" method="post" action='<?= base_url("index.php/welcome");?>'>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectUser" id="seletor">
                     <option  value='<?= $_SESSION["nome"]?>' >Only me</option>
                     <option  value="Trello">Team</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
```

Meu controller:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function index()
 { 
  
  
  
  $nome = $this->input->post('valor');
  var_dump($nome);
 
  $this->load->model('testemodel');

  $verifica= $this->testemodel->verifica($nome);

  $data['nomecliente'] = $verifica['nome_cliente'];
  $data['horatotal'] = $verifica['hora_total'];
  $data['atividade'] = $verifica['nome_atividade'];
  
  
  
 

  $this->load->view('test', $data);
  
  
 }
```

Meu JavaScript:

```js
$("#seletor").change(function(){
 
 var value = $("#seletor").val();
 
 $.ajax({
  url: 'welcome/index',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {"valor" : value},
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
   
  },
  error: function(data){
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

Espero que possam me ajudar. Ficarei muito grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplesmente porque no controller você esta carregando a view:

```
$this->load->view('test', $data);
```

Seria mais facil fazer o retorno json direto:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Está dando esse erro aqui no console.log();

{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

Comment: Da uma olhada no console do browser na aba network se o teu request esta retornando corretamente

Comment: Salvou mano! obrigado mesmo!